# How to store my data using at the end of my step in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form using a Table of `REQUEST` Using `IDRequest (int)`, `TitleOfRequest`
and other Table events which can have multiple events for the same request.

So the Table of events will include :

```
IDEVENTST,
IDRequest,
IDTypeofEvent,
DateStstrong textart,
DateEnd
Table of TYPEOfEvent : IdTypeOfEvent,TitleOfType
```

From my view to create a new record, the record will create at the final step, i want to make it in order

> 1 ) Enter a form with fields `TitleOfRequest`
>     And fields where the person can enter : `DateStart` and `DateEnd`, `TypeOfEvent` and a button to add, and load the temporary records in datatable.

My questions is : what is the best way to store this temporary data with MVC ? And refresh it in my view then at least to save in my database.

Comment: If you are storing these records in the database, doesn't that make them permanent ?

Answer (score -1):

You could use [TempData] if you want to store data for the next request only.TempData allow us to persisting data for the duration of single subsequent request.

If data should be accessible between multiple requests, then use Session.
[Session] is able to store data much more long time, until user session is not expire.

Here is a good blogpost on this matter:

http://petermcintyre.com/2013/01/27/asp-net-mvc-data-persistence-choices/